# Race condition though using transactions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, race-condition

I have this transaction:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
{
    final Payment payment = em.find(Payment.class, id);
    if (payment.status != Status.INIT)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot set to PAID, is not INIT but " + status);

    payment.status = Status.PAID;

}
em.getTransaction().commit();
log.info("Payment " + id + " was paid");
```

However, as you can see here, the transaction does not prevent a race condition:

```
[11:10:18.265] INFO  [PaymentServlet] [MSP] Status COMPLETED 
[11:10:18.265] INFO  [PaymentServlet] Payment c76f9e75-99d7-4721-a8ac-e3a638dd8317 was paid 
[11:10:18.267] INFO  [PaymentServlet] [MSP] Status COMPLETED 
[11:10:18.267] INFO  [PaymentServlet] Payment c76f9e75-99d7-4721-a8ac-e3a638dd8317 was paid
```

The payment is set to `PAID` twice. My exception is not thrown, nor is there a rollback or anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a @Version field in Payment?

Comment: @Anonymoose No, I have no special concurrency things anywhere. I thought that's what transactions are for.

Comment: This IS your "special concurrency thing".

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom no, transactions are not meant to deal with concurrency in that case. To prevent concurrent edits you need some locking mechanism and adding a version field is one way to do that (it's called optimistic locking).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use optimistic locking. Optimistic locking is where conflicting updates are rare so it is acceptable to rollback the occasional transaction when it occurs. Pessimistic locking causes the database to hold a lock on the object while it's in use, effectively single-threading everything and potentially causing performance problems. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking#JPA_2.0_Locking for a more detailed explanation.

To solve the problem here, you should add a field to Payment (the traditional declaration is private Long version) and give it the JPA @Version annotation. If you're managing your schema manually, ensure that a corresponding column exists in the right table. JPA will then use this field to check for conflicting updates and roll back the transaction if a conflict exists.

Update: More on pessimistic locking here: https://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_2_0_concurrency_and In short, you *can* configure JPA to lock objects, but it's extremely rare that it's a good idea to do so. Put another way, if you were hand-coding queries to JDBC, you'd have to write in "for update" at the end of each select to cause pessimistic locking; the default is not to lock on read because it makes databases and database users cry.

Comment: However, shouldn't it have applied pessimistic (or really any kind of) locking here automatically? Right now the transaction does not do the one thing I expect it to do: maintaining integrity. Is my understanding of transactions wrong? (Do I have to update all my JPA code now? XD )

Comment: Not in practice. ACID is very expensive. The usual default "repeatable reads" level of isolation is typically a good tradeoff for exactly the same reason that optimistic locking rarely causes a rollback, which is that conflicts are rare unless provoked. You still get Atomicity (all or nothing), Consistency (whole DB won't go invalid), and Durability (a commit won't disappear), though. Mostly. Again, tradeoffs.

Comment: You may be confusing ACID with one of the more common techniques for achieving it: strict two-phase locking (S2PL). Serializable Snapshot Isolation has fewer rollbacks under high contention than Optimistic Concurrency Control (OCC), without the blocking and deadlocks of S2PL.

Comment: Done intentionally to summarize the matter, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what database you are using, or what transaction isolation level.  If you use `SERIALIZABLE` transactions which conform to the SQL standard you will not see this error.  PostgreSQL versions before 9.1, some configurations of MS SQL Server, and all versions of Oracle don't give your real serializable transactions when you ask for them, so explicit locks must be used in such environments.  Most database products default to `READ COMMITTED` transaction isolation level, so you would probably need to explicitly request `SERIALIZABLE` transactions.

Full disclosure, I worked with Dan R.K. Ports of MIT to add the true serializable transactions to PostgreSQL version 9.1, so that the Wisconsin Courts software could deal with these issues cleanly.  For examples of the difference, see [this Wiki page](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI).

Comment: It's PostgreSQL 9.0.5, and I don't explicitly set any isolation level.

Comment: Then you must use some form of explicit locking.  Options include optimistic locking as described in another answer, an advisory lock, an explicit table lock, or any of a number of other solutions coded at the application level.  Or you could upgrade to 9.1 and use SERIALIZABLE transactions.  This chapter in the PostgreSQL docs may help: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/mvcc.html

Comment: Upgrading might be possible, I'll look into that. By the way, what do you get when you request Serializable before 9.1, and why doesn't it throw a "I don't really support this" error?